# How do I get an object with LoopBack using a parameter taken from another query

Tags: javascript, mongodb, loopbackjs

I will try to be as clear as possible but please ask if I am missing some detail.

So I have an application that I've inherited and it's running slow. It was built with Angular and Typescript on the front end, Loopback handling our CRUD operations and a Mongo DB. We isolated one of the reasons for the slowness as excess REST calls (potentially tens of thousands at times) so I am looking at reducing this. The first one I have found is a relatively small one so I hoped it'd help me to learn but I've already hit a challenge. Descriptions, table names and finer detail has been removed for simplicity.

On the first page, we present to the user a list of links to areas that they have access to. This is stored in an "Areas" table. We pull back all of the areas in a function similar to this:

```
this.ourApi.areas.find({
    "filter": {
        "include": ["generalInfo"]
        /*
           This table is related to most tables and
           holds things like version numbers - it
           is not relevant to this question
        */
    }
}).$promise.then((returnedAreas) => {
    /* Stuff */
});
```

After we have all the areas, we then have to get some configuration values for these area links (icons, mostly). Our configuration table holds configuration data for a number of items, not just Areas. So to get the relevant config information, we loop through the `returnedAreas` and, for each area, get the config where the `relatedId` matches the `areaId`. A bit like this:

```
return this.ourApi.configs.find({
    "filter": {
        "where": {
            "relatedId": areaId
        },
        "include": ["generalInfo"]
    }
}).$promise.then((areaConfigurations) => {
    /* Stuff */
});
```

Ideally, I'd like to compress this down to just one call (and then mimic this pattern throughout the application). The only thing we really care about (and the only objects we actually use) are the configuration objects so we really don't need the "Areas" objects at all. The challenge I am unable to solve is how I adjust that second call above (that gets the config) so that it first gets the Areas and then uses the areaId in the query that gets the data that I care about. In SQl, this would be quite easy but I can't figure it out from the docs.

Essentially, I am looking for the Loopback equivalent of:

```
SELECT * FROM configs WHERE relatedId IN (SELECT areaId FROM areas)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Maybe this is what you are searching for: https://www.codeschool.com/discuss/t/how-to-query-based-on-the-variable-value-stored-in-another-field/20979 ?

Comment: If I get you right, both queries are run for the same page. In this case to reduce number of calls you can just embed areas data to the configuration document so you search configs by data you use to filter areas in the first query. In general, it seems to me that your schema should be reviewed and refactored according to your application's data access patterns.

Comment: Why do you need to loop instead of using relation? Is it right to rewrite your desired query as `SELECT * FROM configs JOIN areas ON configs.relatedId = areas.areaId` ? In such case I think that solution in Loopback is obvious.